# Two ways change UIView frame ，any differents?

Tags: ios, cgrect

I tried to change a uiview's frame in two ways, code is below:

-- 1 --

```
CGRect f = self.myView.frame;
f.origin.x = 2.0;
f.origin.y = 3.0;
f.size.width = 10.0;
f.size.width = 10.0;
self.myView.frame = f;
```

-- 2 --

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 10.0);
```

I ran the code in an old iPod Touch 3. In debug mode, they are not different. In release mode, the first code block doesn't work correctly. Why?

By the way, I found the open project "MBProgressHUD" has the same problem.

Comment: sorry, here first code not set the height. But in my project's code is right.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the height of the CGRect in the first code.

Answer (score 0):

The first line sets the width twic. It doesn't set the height.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frame of UIView with the two following mode:

```
CGRect f = myView.frame;
f.origin.x = 2.0;
f.origin.y = 3.0;
f.size.width = 10.0;
f.size.height = 10.0;
myView.frame = f;
```

or

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 10.0)];
```